# Multiple Empty View for one ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView, with an Empty View that shows a progressbar to indicate that the app is still loading. I want to make a second empty view to tell the user if there is some error during the process.

I have tried with 2 relative layouts, but when I need to set the "error view", it just ignore it and shows only the "loading view".

So I have tried with a single layout, with my progressbar and the others things to make the error screen, with VISIBILITY:GONE. But, when it's time to put VISIBILITY to VISIBLE, I receive a NullPointerException.

I don't really know what I'm supposed to do to make it works... Thank you!

---

**EDIT**
this is my Layout right now (the VISIBILITY attempt) UNDER the ListView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/post_list_loading">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/post_list_loading_progressbar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/post_list_error_image"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/post_list_error_image"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/post_list_error_image"
            android:text="Error Text"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/post_list_error_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post_list_error_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/post_list_error_text"
            android:text="Ricarica"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The first method I have tried was about putting everything after the progressbar in another RelativeLayout.

So my idea was to make a function to switch between the two views, playing with the Visibility settings.

```
public void emptyViewManager(Boolean isError, String errorMessage)
{
    // [...]

    if (isError == true)
    {
        // Error View
        emptyView_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView_errorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyView_errorText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyView_errorButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        emptyView_errorText.setText(errorMessage);
    }

    else
    {
        // Loading View
        emptyView_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyView_errorImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView_errorText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView_errorButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

But this didn't work because I have a NullPointerException when the App reach the setVisibility function.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: OK! I have added the layout and the function to hide and show the components right now.